# Can I setup a single button to clean+ re-build in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, gradle

Is there a way I can clean and rebuild in Android Studio from a button (in the top menu bar) or a keyboard short in a single command?

At present, I use the menu (I'm quite new to this..) Build > Clean Project, then Build > Re-Build project.

I've got a gut feeling there has to be a better way. Seeing if anyone's got the magic figured out already?

Comment: you can write your own gradle command for that